# NSURLSession's dataTaskWithRequest: returns nil

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession, nsurlrequest

I've got a really strange error. I have the following line in code:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
```

after execution of which the `task` is `nil`! This case is not documented anywhere and I couldn't find any similar cases on the web. The `session` is not `nil`.

This happens only when I press home to leave the app, come back and do something that sends a request. *iOS Simulator 8.3*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [bug in iOS](https://devforums.apple.com/message/926113#926113), sometimes it just returns nil. Workaround for this is to keep calling this method for several times, just like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1675) does for `uploadTaskWithRequest:` method.

Comment: the reason for me was calling [self.session invalidateAndCancel] when app enters background :)